# How to build an Android list view using data from multidimentional array or two separate arrays?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to build a menu that should have Title and Description for each menu item. I tried to use two dimensional array and I tried to use two separate arrays. Can't make it work. Below is my last code. Thank you for your help.

I get an Exception pointing to this line of code and activity simply crashes:

```
listView.setAdapter(channelNamesAdapter);
```

**Full Class is below:**

```
public class ChanelMenuActivity extends ListActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);


    ListView listView;

    String[] channelNames = new String[] { "Title1", "Title2", "Title3" };

    String[] channelDescriptions = new String[] { "Description1", "Description1", "Description1" };

    ArrayAdapter channelNamesAdapter;
    listView =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_items); 
    channelNamesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, channelNames);
    listView.setAdapter(channelNamesAdapter);


    ArrayAdapter channelDescriptionAdapter;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_items); 
    channelDescriptionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.description, channelDescriptions);
    listView.setAdapter(channelDescriptionAdapter);


  }
```

**my rowlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="173px"
        android:layout_height="107px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/thumb" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/description"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hard work and many tutorial I finally made it work. Here is how I achieved what I needed. Very nicely done menu list. Every menu item has 3 objects: Image, Title and Description. OnClickListener is in place as well. Tapping on the menu item will launch a Toast. Data for all menu objects comes from array.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent channelIntent = new Intent(this, ChanelMenuActivity.class);
        //i.putExtra("value1", result.toString());
        startActivity (channelIntent);

    }
}
```

**ChanelMenuActivity.java**

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChanelMenuActivity extends ListActivity {

    Level data[] = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ListView lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewIgor);
        final Level data[] = new Level[]
                {
            new Level(R.drawable.icon, "Heading 1", "Description 1"),
            new Level(R.drawable.thumb, "Heading 2", "Description 2"),
            new Level(R.drawable.mplayer, "Heading 3", "Description 3"),
            new Level(R.drawable.thumb, "Heading 4", "Description 4"),
            new Level(R.drawable.mplayer, "Heading 5", "Description 5"),
            new Level(R.drawable.icon, "Heading 6", "Description 6"),
            new Level(R.drawable.thumb, "Heading 7", "Description 7"),
            new Level(R.drawable.mplayer, "Heading 8", "Description 8"),
            new Level(R.drawable.icon, "Heading 9", "Description 9"),
            new Level(R.drawable.thumb, "Heading 10", "Description 9"),
            new Level(R.drawable.mplayer, "Heading 11", "Description 10"),
            new Level(R.drawable.icon, "Heading 12", "Description 11"),
            new Level(R.drawable.thumb, "Heading 13", "Description 12"),
            new Level(R.drawable.mplayer, "Heading 14", "Description 13"),
            new Level(R.drawable.icon, "Heading 15", "Description 14")

                };

        LevelAdapter adp=new LevelAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, data);
        lv1.setAdapter(adp);


        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(
                new OnItemClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id){
                        System.out.println("Igor's Click Was heard");

                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                        Context context = getApplicationContext();

                        Level channelData = data[position];

                        CharSequence text = channelData.title;
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        onCreate(icicle);
                    }
                }
                );

  }


  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu){
    //This one will respond to More Options menu click at the top right
    Toast.makeText(this, "item" + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;

  }
}
```

**Level.java**

```
public class Level {
    public int icon;
    public String title;
    public String title2;

    public Level()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Level(int icon, String title, String title2) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.title2 = title2;
    }

}
```

**LevelAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LevelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Level> {

     static Context context;
        static int layoutResourceId;   
         Level data[] = null;

     public LevelAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Level[] data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }


        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ChannelDataHolder holder = null;

            if(row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
               //row.setMinimumHeight(200);
                holder = new ChannelDataHolder();
                holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle2);

                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ChannelDataHolder)row.getTag();
            }

            Level channelData = data[position];
            holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(channelData.icon);
            holder.txtTitle.setText(channelData.title);
            holder.txtTitle2.setText(channelData.title2);

            return row;
        }

        static class ChannelDataHolder
        {
            ImageView imgIcon;
            TextView txtTitle;
            TextView txtTitle2;
        }

}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="173px"
        android:layout_height="107px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewIgor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tv.emoe.www"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                <activity android:name="ChanelMenuActivity"></activity>
                <activity android:name="LevelAdapter"></activity>
                <activity android:name="Level"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) create your own class which will have the `channelName` and `channelDescription` attributes, use getters and setters

2) Extend `BaseAdapter`

3) Use `ArrayList<yourClass>` for the adapter data

**EDIT** example:

```
public class MyClass{

  private String channelName, channelDescription;

    public MyClass(){
   /* default constructor */
    }

 public void setName(String channelName){
    this.channelName = channelName;
   }
    public void setDesc(String channelDescription){
    this.channelName = channelDescription;
   }

   public String getName(){
    return this.channelName;
   }
   public String getDesc(){
    return this.channelDescription;
   }
}
```

setting up data in your `Activity`:

```
 ArrayList<MyClass> data = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  MyClass mc = new MyClass();
  mc.setName("Name " + i);
  mc.setDesc("Desc " + i);
  data.add(mc);
 }

 myListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, data));
```

MyAdapter class:

```
  public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<MyClass> data;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ViewHolder holder;

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvName, tvDesc;
}

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<MyClass> data, Context c) {
    this.data = data;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyClass item = (MyClass) getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_list_row, null);

        holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
         holder.tvDesc = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvItemDesc);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.tvDesc.setText(item.getDesc());
    return convertView;
}

 }
```